# Difference between 職務 and 業務

Tags: word-choice

Could you please explain the difference in meaning between 職務 ｛しょくむ｝ and 業務｛ぎょうむ｝? In which context are each of them the most suitable?

Comment: What have you been able to find out so far?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @l'électeur. 
Till now, I just know, that they mean some work, duties inside a single position. But as I tried to find some clear difference between them, I have got lost... I see their kanji, but still can't feel the exact difference.

Answer (score 4):

[事業{じぎょう}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BA%8B%E6%A5%AD) means business or industry.

[業務{ぎょうむ}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A5%AD%E5%8B%99) means work done in reference to a business.

[職務{しょくむ}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%81%B7%E5%8B%99) means duties in reference to one's job or position.

To break it down, 事業{じぎょう} is what your company does, 業務{ぎょうむ} is what your department does, and 職務{しょくむ} is what you do.For example, if you worked in a video game company, the 事業{じぎょう} is the production and sales of video games. Within the company, you have departments like  production, sales and marketing; what they do falls under 業務{ぎょうむ}. And within sales, you have people with their own 職務{しょくむ}, like salesmen, people writing the invoices, people in charge of the inventory, etc.

Note that 業務 is often used to mean "business" or "commerical" like 業務連絡{ぎょうむれんらく} (business page) and 業務用冷蔵庫{ぎょうむようれいぞうこ} (commercial refrigerator.

Answer (score 1):

職務 refers to your **personal** responsibility/duty as a businessperson. 職務 is something assigned to each employee. For example "dereliction of duty" is 職務怠慢, not 業務怠慢.

業務 is *business*; everything your company does as a whole to earn money. For example Amazon's 業務 is online retailing and cloud computing. In the legal language 業務 means something much broader, but that's another story.